# how to extract common aspects from text using deep learning?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, text

Can you suggest me some papers to read about deep learning models that find patterns/similarities between different texts?

What I have is a set of reviews with the following categories for each review: Rating, Review title, Review body, date, and helpful votes.
What I would like to do is understand whether there exist similarities among the reviews. For instance, there exists a cluster of customers that complains about a specific aspect of a product.
Or, as another example, to see if there exists a problem related to the season e.g. a product has many bad reviews in summer because it does not work well with high temperatures.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Imho this is not feasible as such (I might be wrong). Because basically this would mean an unsupervised way to focus on a specific kind of similarity which is not predefined, and I think there are too many unknowns in this problem. You and I have some understanding of what kind of semantic information is intereesting, but the unsupervised model doesn't: for instanceit might consider it a similarity that a group of reviews contain the word 'right' or contain N times the letter 'x', or contain exactly 274 characters... How would it know what is a relevant similarity?

Comment: You may be interested in the Aspect Based Sentiment Analysis literature. I think there are approaches for automatic detection of Aspects, probably a pre-trained transformer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is called by several different names: multi-aspect, semi-supervised, or hierarchical topic modeling.

One way to approach the problem is to start with a seed or anchor words (e.g., "winter" and "summer") and form clusters around those words.

It can be solved with a variety of methods, the most commonly used methods are variations of Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA).